# Number of Pdf pages for IEnumerable

Tags: .net

Below is my algoritm to calculate the number of pages needed to build my pdf file, so I can add to the bottom of the page some pagination. Ex: "totalPages = 4" then the pdf prints at the bottom "somePageNumberVariable / 4".

Currently it is failing in some cases where it calculates one page more than needed. Any way to improve the algoritm? Any ideas would be great. Thanks.

```
int idx, pckIdx, totalPages;
bool increment;

foreach (MyObject item in result.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
{
    idx = 0;
    increment = false;
    itemsGrouped = item.Lines.GroupBy(grp => grp.Order);

    foreach (var itemLineGrp in itemsGrouped.OrderBy(r => r.Key))
    {
        pckIdx = 1;

        foreach (MyObjectLine itemLine in itemLineGrp)
        {
            if (idx % rowsPerPage == 0 && idx != 0)
            {
                totalPages++;
                idx = 0;
            }

            idx++;
            increment = true;
        }

        if (idx % rowsPerPage == 0 && idx != 0)
        {
            totalPages++;
            idx = 0;
        }
    }

    totalPages++;
}

public class MyObject 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<MyObjectLine> Lines  { get; set }  
    // Other props
}

public class MyObjectLine
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    // Other props
}
```

Comment: This isn't uncommon: I've seen a **LOT** of things over the years that end up with an extra blank page, to the point of receiving this pages through physical snail mail. But I suspect the issue is in the case where the inner loops end up _exactly_ at the bottom of the page, the last `totalPages++` at the bottom of the outer loop is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried that, but in some cases then the page number is one number short.